# Dynamic/Conditional SQL Join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have data in a MSSQL table (TableB) where [dbo].tableB.myColumn changes format after a certain date...

I'm doing a simple Join to that table..

```
Select [dbo].tableB.theColumnINeed from [dbo].tableA 
left outer join [dbo].tableB on [dbo].tableA.myColumn = [dbo].tableB.myColumn
```

However, I need to join, using different formatting, based on a date column in Table A ([dbo].tableA.myDateColumn).

Something like...

```
Select [dbo].tableB.theColumnINeed from [dbo].tableA 
left outer join [dbo].tableB on [dbo].tableA.myColumn = 
    IF [dbo].tableA.myDateColumn > '1/1/2009'
        BEGIN
            FormatColumnOneWay([dbo].tableB.myColumn)
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            FormatColumnAnotherWay([dbo].tableB.myColumn)
        END
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to do this.. or a better way I'm not thinking of to approach this..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT [dbo].tableB.theColumnINeed
FROM   [dbo].tableA 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].tableB
ON [dbo].tableA.myColumn = 
   CASE
    WHEN [dbo].tableA.myDateColumn <= '1/1/2009' THEN FormatColumnOneWay([dbo].tableB.myColumn)
    ELSE FormatColumnAnotherWay([dbo].tableB.myColumn)
   END
```

Answer (score 5):

Rather than having a CASE statement in the JOIN, which will prevent the query using indexes, you could consider using a UNION

```
SELECT [dbo].tableB.theColumnINeed 
FROM   [dbo].tableA 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].tableB 
         ON [dbo].tableA.myDateColumn > '1/1/2009'
        AND [dbo].tableA.myColumn = FormatColumnOneWay([dbo].tableB.myColumn)
UNION ALL
SELECT [dbo].tableB.theColumnINeed 
FROM   [dbo].tableA 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].tableB 
         ON [dbo].tableA.myDateColumn <= '1/1/2009'
        AND [dbo].tableA.myColumn = FormatColumnAnotherWay([dbo].tableB.myColumn)
```

but if the FormatColumnOneWay / FormatColumnAnotherWay are functions, or field expressions, that is probably going to exclude use of inxdexes on [myColumn], although any index on myDateColumn should still be used

However, it might help to understand what the FormatColumnOneWay / FormatColumnAnotherWay logic is, as knowning that may enable a better optimisation

Couple of things to note:

UNION ALL will not remove any duplicates (unlike UNION). Because the two sub-queries are mutually exclusive this is OK and saves the SORT step which UNION would make to enable it to remove duplicates.

You should not use '1/1/2009' style for string-dates, you should use 'yyyymmdd' style without and slashes or hyphens (you can also use CONVERT with an parameter to explicitly indicate that the string is in d/m/y or m/d/y style

Answer (score 0):

From the `[dbo]` prefix, I believe you're using SQL Server. While I don't have much experience with it, you can convert both fields to a specific date format:

```
select * from tableA
  Left Outer join tableB
       On CONVERT(CHAR(8), tableA.myColumn, 112) = CONVERT(CHAR(8), tableB.myColumn, 112)
```

The same should work on any DBMS, using the appropriate date formatting functions.

I don't know about SQL Server, but in Oracle you can create an index for the join expression.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you'd use a CASE such as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB on TableA.Column=
CASE WHEN TableA.RecordDate>'1/2/08'
       THEN FormatCoumn(TableB.Column) 
     ELSE FormatColumnOtherWat(TableB.Column)
END
```

Comment: My suggestion would be to fix the data because the optimizer will disregard indexes with those functions in the JOIN condition

Comment: Yes but sometimes you can't fix the data;-)

Comment: It is the same column, I would fix it, put a CHECK CONSTRAINT on it so that it won't happen again because sooner or later someone will scream that performance is unacceptable and then what?

Answer (score 0):

You know that this is bad for performance since you won't be able to use indexes right?

You can use a CASE statement kludge or...you can go and fix the data so that you CAN use the index and it will be many times faster

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use a subquery to properly format the data in either table before the join.

```
SELECT
  newB.columnINeed
FROM
  tableA AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT
    columnINeed
  , CASE WHEN myColumn > '1/1/2009' THEN FormatColumnOneWay(myColumn)
    ELSE FormatColumnAnotherWay(myColumn)
    END AS myColumn
  FROM
    tableB
) AS NewB ON A.myColumn = B.myColumn
```

If performance matters, you could maybe used an indexed view (based on the subquery) instead of hard-coding the subquery into the overall query.

Comment: You may not be able to do this. I notice you are formatting B on the basis of A. My guess is you can probably format B without involving A, then do the join?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that a `CASE` syntax would be more appropriate for reading purposes, although I don't know whether there's any significant difference in running time.

The "right" thing to do, really, is to re-do it and do it right to start with. Your dates should be stored in `datetime` columns, and you probably have quite a lot to gain on migrating all your dates in tableB to a datetime column. You could do it this way, among others:

1. Add a dummie column to `TableB` with type `datetime`.
2. Run a query that takes the date value from the current column and puts it in the datetime column.
3. Rename and delete columns to match the previous data structure.

Comment: You forgot step 4: Spend weeks or months hunting down all the errors caused in other code/reports from deleting a column

Comment: Well, datetime values not stored in datetime columns are also evil. Depending on how large the application using the database is, there might be a lot of problems - yes, but if you've used a good separation of concerns etc you won't have a lot of places to change. Why spend time hacking smelly code?

Comment: He does say it is a date column, he never actually said it was a varchar/nvarchar/whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, hold up.  What is the actual data type of the column?  I'm guessing it isn't DateTime, because you don't really control the formatting... it just stores a date.  Can it be CAST or CONVERTed to a DateTime though?

So you might want

```
left outer join tableb on tableA.myColumn = CAST(tableb.MyColumn as DateTime)
```

That way you're not matching up a string, but the actual date which should be more reliable.  It's also simpler and easier to read.  The real questions is why the date isn't stored as a DateTime in hte first place...