# MySQL dynamically selecting fields within join?

Tags: mysql

I am looking to dynamically select specific columns within a join query in which a specific field will only be selected if the value of another is not equal to 0.

So here's what I have going on.

The query uses the following 3 tables, users - schools - campuses

I would like to select all of the data from users, and if the campus_id field of users is not equal to 0, then I would like to include the campus name field of campuses where campuses.id = users.campus_id, how would I do this?

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566600/dynamic-conditional-sql-join

Comment: @Braydon: every result row must have the same number of columns. What do you want the value of the column to be if the campus_id is 0? Also, [sample code](http://sscce.org/) speaks volumes. Please include the table schema (as `CREATE TABLE` statements), sample data (as `INSERT` statements), as much of the query as you have, results of the query and desired results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional column for query based on other columns in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849348/conditional-column-for-query-based-on-other-columns-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT column1, column2, (CASE WHEN U.campus_id<>0 THEN campus_name) FROM USERS U, CAMPUSES C
WHERE (U.campus_id <>0 AND C.id=U.campus_id)
```

Comment: How would I do this if I want more than 1 where condition?

Comment: @BraydonBatungbacal the you could use CASE WHEN .... THEN ... WHEN ... THEN .... ELSE check the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select * from users u  
left join campuses c on (u.campus_id = c.id)
```